# How to filter a python list?

Tags: python, json

I have a list and I need to filter that list and get some key values. this is the list:

```
"products":[  
      {  
         "discount":"0.00000",
         "id":"6f47e339-34a0-8c58-11e7-9f96677d9fcc",
         "loyalty_value":"0.00000",
         "price":"0.00000",
         "price_set":false,
         "price_total":"0.00000",
         "product_id":"0af7b240-ab09-11e7-eddc-8cb82351211c",
         "quantity":1,
      },
      {  
         "discount":"0.00000",
         "id":"6f47e339-34a0-8c58-11e7-9f966ecf8e5f",
         "loyalty_value":"0.00000",
         "price":"3.18182",
         "price_set":false,
         "price_total":"3.18182",
         "product_id":"0af7b240-ab09-11e7-eddc-80d691bbf094",
         "quantity":1,
      },
      {  
         "discount":"0.00000",
         "id":"6f47e339-34a0-8c58-11e7-9f96701777b2",
         "loyalty_value":"0.00000",
         "price":"2.72727",
         "price_set":false,
         "price_total":"2.72727",
         "product_id":"0af7b240-ab09-11e7-eddc-80a522346b58",
         "quantity":1,
      }

   ]
```

I need to get the same list from above list after filtration like:

```
"LstProduct": [
    {
      "product_id": "string",
      "price": 0,
      "quantity": 0
    },
    {
      "product_id": "string",
      "price": 0,
      "quantity": 0
    }, 
    {
      "product_id": "string",
      "price": 0,
      "quantity": 0
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may create a new list having the keys you need for your new list. Then you may filter the result using *list comprehension* as:

```
filtered_keys = ["product_id", "price", "quantity"]

new_list = [{key: element[key] for key in filtered_keys} for element in old_list]
```

where `old_list` is list of your dict objects.

Comment: Happy to help @NitinSherawat. If you find any answer useful to your question on SO, you should mark the [best answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow). For details, please check: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I would suggest to modify existing list instead of creating new

Comment: Actually I need to modify key name in result, now I am getting the same key .

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri is there something where I can modify key names in result. fo example Now I am getting result like :     {
      "product_id": "string",
      "price": 0,
      "quantity": 0
    } and I need to change it like:     {
      "ProductId": "string",
      "ProductPrice": 0,
      "ProductQty": 0
    }